# open ports on external ip

Tags: ip, port-forwarding, nmap

I scanned my external ip address that was issued by my isp.
Some ports are open and I don't understand if they should be open or closed.
I thought port 631 ipp is for remote printers. I only use local printers.
Are all these ports supposed to be open or some need to be closed?

Thanks [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOUzd.jpg)

Comment: Have you checked yet whether you are subject to [CGNAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT)? Compare the public IP address your router reports with the IP address that “what is my IP” websites on the internet show. “Your” IP address may not be yours at all. // What’s your router’s make and model? Can you even configure port forwarding in its web interface? Do you perhaps have a optical network terminal or some other type of modem as a separate device?

Comment: @DanielB Router is nighthawk R6700v3. The ip I scanned was what is my ip address. I do more scanning later. The modem is separate from router. I don't have port forwarding enabled. So what is my ip is different from isp ip?

Comment: Ah, something I also missed: Did you scan your IP address from _inside_ your network?

Comment: Good thinking @DanielB. I tried it using my phone tethering with wifi off and the results came as: 80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
Now is http on port 80 suppose to be open? I have an NVR if that matters.

Comment: What is this warning? WARNING: Service MY-IP-ADDRESS:4444 had already soft-matched rtsp, but now soft-matched sip; ignoring second value.  I used Vulscan.